# Autostart permission programmatically

Tags: android, autostart, moto, oppo

I am working on an app where I need to ask user for the autostart permission and for that I am opening the Autostart permissions settings page for the user to turn on the permission for our app using following code for few Manufacturers:

```
Intent autostartIntent = new Intent();
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
       autostartIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
       startActivity(autostartIntent);
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
       autostartIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
       startActivity(autostartIntent);
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
       autostartIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
       startActivity(autostartIntent);
    } else if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
       autostartIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
       startActivity(autostartIntent);
}
```

Moreover, when I am trying to redirect user to the following devices, I am facing following difficulties:

1. On RealMe 2 Pro, for which the manufacturer is Oppo, the system is unable to start the AutoStart Permissions Activity.
2. On Moto and Nokia devices, I am not able to get the path of AutoStart Activity, so that I can redirect user to that page directly.

Comment: just asking for clarification: have you tested on Huawei with this code sample ? I used to know the manufacturer name as 'Honor'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to this question, i am opening the Battery Optimization page for the user to turn off Battery Optimization for my app.

Here is the code i am using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PermissionsActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Turn off Battery Optimization");
    builder.setMessage("Find XYZ in the list of applications and choose ‘Don’t optimize’.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Allow",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```