# Android: set alarm/reminder after phone reboot

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, android-reboot

I'm developing an Android app with a reminder function integrated.
The notifications work if the phone stay on, but when I turn it off or reboot it I lose all my alarms.
I know that this is and Android feature to improve the phone efficency, but I don't know what to do about this, how can I solve this problem?

Here my files:

- AlarmService.java
- AlarmReceiver.java
- BootAlarmReceiver.java
- AndroidManifest.xml

"AlarmService.java" is called by "BootAlarmReceiver.java" when the phone is turned on and it **should**, but it doesn't, reload all my alarms.
"AlarmReceiver.java" is called when an alarm is fired from AlarmManager.

Here the code:

**AlarmService.java**

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    int requestCode, year, month, day, hour, minute;
    String note, with;

    try {
        fileInputStream = openFileInput("my_alarms.csv");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String row;

        while ((row = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splittedRow = row.split(";");
            requestCode = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[0]);
            year = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[1]);
            month = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[2]);
            day = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[3]);
            hour = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[4]);
            minute = Integer.valueOf(splittedRow[5]);
            note = splittedRow[6];
            with = splittedRow[7];

            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("note", note + "\nCon: " + with);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("title", "My Memo");
            alarmIntent.putExtra("alarm", "memo");

            //requestCode must be incremental to create multiple reminders
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, alarmIntent, 0);

            if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra("alarm").equals("memo")) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("memo_channel", "My Memo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Memo Notification Channel");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "memo_channel");
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setTicker("Reminder")
                    .setContentTitle("Memo")
                    .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("note"))
                    .setContentInfo("Information")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm);

            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**BootAlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class BootAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
            ComponentName service = context.startService(alarmServiceIntent);

            if (service == null) {
                Log.e("ALARM", "Could not start service");
            } else {
                Log.e("ALARM", "Could start service");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        //Other code here

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootAlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <service android:name=".AlarmService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me, thank you for your time.

**EDIT**

I found this error when device turn on:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.package.appname.BootAlarmReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=REBOOT cmp=com.package.appname/.AlarmService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{a5a4cb2 u0a341 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

What should I do?

Comment: which devices (brand) you lost alarms ?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi I'm using my physical device LG G6.
Then I discovered this error:
Unable to start receiver com.package.appname.BootAlarmReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Hi guys, I've found the issue I was having, my code is right and it works fine, the problem was in the OS of my device, from Android OS Oreo the command to start a service is changed and is needed a new command syntax:

The changement is in "BootAlarmReceiver.java"

PREVIOUS CODE:

```
public class BootAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
            ComponentName service = context.startService(alarmServiceIntent);

            if (service == null) {
                Log.e("ALARM", "Could not start service");
            } else {
                Log.e("ALARM", "Could start service");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
public class BootAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(alarmServiceIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(alarmServiceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you are running on Oreo or newer you should use `.startForegroundService(yourIntent)`, otherwise you should use `.startService(yourIntent)`.

This solution should work also for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some brands are using extra policies to fasten boot up and battery optimization. For example Xiaomi has auto-start permission for this. If you want your alarms is continuing without interruption after reboot, you must be granted for this permission. (Settings/Apps/Your app/Auto Start). Many manufacturer have something like this.

What can you  do ?

You can ask for auto start permission programmatically, or ask for ignoring battery optimization permission.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307864/11982611

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167712/11982611

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325917/11982611

Those are some question/answers would help you

Edit : Your logs says you don't have the permission to go start your service when boot completed.

You must google "how to whitelist your app in LG6" and "how to get auto start permission for LG". For this issue is brand and device related. It is impossible for me to tell exactly what you should do.

Even you say you checked everything, there is something missing with permissions

Comment: Thank you, now I will take a look to these topics and I will let you know if it will work

Comment: I've checked everything and my application has all the permission to start on boot... I still don't know what to do.